# How to create a perfect half circle with CGPathAddCurveToPoint?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, cgpath

I am trying to create a perfect right half circle of 15 points radius with CGPathAddCurveToPoint, like this:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 15, 0, 15, 30, 0, 30);
```

It starts at the top middle of the circle.
Then the first control point is set to the top right corner of the circle's bounding box.
The second control point is set to the bottom right corner of the circle's bounding box.
The circle ends at bottom middle of the bounding box.

But when drawn, the circle has an egg-like shape.

How can I make a perfect, flawless right semisphere starting at point 0,0 going to the right and ending at 0,30?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGPathAddCurveToPoint` creates a [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve), not a circular arc. The method you’re looking for is `CGPathAddArc` or `CGPathAddArcToPoint`, as below:

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 0, 15, 15, M_PI_2, -M_PI_2, true);
```

Comment: Perfect! But how did you know that you will need to provide half of PI, and half of PI negative?

Comment: Trigonometry. Half of pi is 90 degrees in radians. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle

Comment: That's what I mean... the arc starts at the center of the circle, at 0,15 and you provide 90 degrees as start angle. Shouldn't the top be 0 degrees like a clock, and 90 degrees at 3'o clock (center right)? Very confusing. But anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: The angles are specified in a coordinate system unrelated to the intended start and end points of the arc. By convention, 0 degrees is the rightmost edge of the unit circle in the X/Y plane, and increasing angles go counterclockwise around the circle.