# CGPathAddArc path not appearing in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Using Xcode 6 beta 6, I am able to draw a straight path, but whenever I use `CGPathAddArc` or `CGPathAddArcToPoint`, the path does not appear.

Following the answer from this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012807/how-to-create-a-perfect-half-circle-with-cgpathaddcurvetopoint), the following should draw a half circle.

```
var line = SKShapeNode()
line.zPosition = 3
line.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 15, 15, CGFloat(M_PI_2), CGFloat(-M_PI_2), true);
line.path = path
line.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
self.addChild(line)
```

Unfortunately, nothing appears. If I change `CGPathAddArc` to `CGPathAddLineToPoint` a path is successfully drawn on the screen. Is the code above incorrect?

Comment: Given that CGPathAddLineToPoint is working, have you tried CGPathAddArcToPoint? There's an attempt to tell the difference between the two AddArc's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127/cgpathaddarc-vs-cgpathaddarctopoint but it means nothing to me.

Comment: @Confused: The problem exists with CGPathAddArcToPoint as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem and it looks like a bug. This problem appeared after upgrading to Xcode 6 beta 6. The same code correctly drew a circle in Xcode 6 beta 1.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, if I had enough reputation points, I would do as you say. This is my first day on the stackoverflow, and in the future i will do it more competently

Comment: My question was "Is the above code incorrect?", and @alex_p gave an answer to my question that seems correct. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Add one more thing: this problem occurs only on the simulator, on a real device everything works fine.